# external structure to store gsl matrices

Tags: c, memory

I am wondering if there is some kind of a database or memory structure where I can keep my data during program evaluation and access them easily. 
Here is the problem: I am writing program in C which operates on complex matrices. Those matrices are created once and then other functions use them to calculate different quantities. My idea was to keep them somewhere where I can easily access them without storing in RAM memory. This "memory structure" should know that these are gsl_matrix_complex structures. Does anything like this exist ?

Answer (score 0):

Apologies for asking this question in an answer block but my reputation does not allow me to ask questions as a 'comment' :)

I am curious about your need to NOT want to store the matrices in memory but I suspect that you requirement of 'off-memory' storage maybe a terminology issue. Can you please elaborate on your question? What volume of data are we talking about? MB's? GB's? TB's?

Processing data from memory is SIGNIFICANTLY faster and than processing data from disk.

Although I am unfamiliar with gsl_matrix_complex, you may wish to consider using a C structure (or levels of structures) that store your matrices on disk. When you need to process these matrices, read them from disk, directly into the structure(s), and process their data from the structures - IE, memory. This, assumes of course, that the volume of workable data you are talking about is reasonable to store in memory and applicable the the machine you are processing this on. If the volume of data you are processing is significant (and I'm talking GB's, TB's etc), you will need to consider an efficient structure and disk-file recording system whereby you can load 'chunks' into memory and process those chunks.

Good luck with your endeavors!